# Really a 4 month gap between our 1st and 2nd question? Or, do bad questions go away?

Tags: discussion

At the bottom of page 71, there is a question about 
[plotting discontinuous functions without spurious vertical segments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10501/plotting-discontinuous-functions-without-spurious-vertical-segments), which is dated Dec 7, 2010.  The next question, about [default color data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4712/how-to-change-the-default-colordata-used-in-mathematicas-plot), is dated Mar 22, 2011. What happened to the intervening questions? Not worth saving? Who deleted them?

Do the moderators try to structure and organize as we go, deleting questions with zero scores and duplicate questions?

Comment: If you look at those old questions, they'll say "migrated from [so]" (or whichever site) under the question.

Answer (score 6):

They were questions that were once housed at our sister site, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and migrated here, since they were thought to be more suitable for this site.

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1) is the very first question that was asked on this site. Note that all the questions that come before it chronologically came from SO.